# Getting Error while trying to load DLL using DllImport in windows 10 universal app

Tags: windows, dll, dllimport, windows-10-universal

I am creating windows app. which is targeting windows 10 platform and it is **Universal Windows App** and I am using **https://github.com/phatware/WritePadSDK** for creating writing lad in windows app. Now what i have done is in the solution that i downloaded from github i added a project that targeted the windows universal app. I have added all the needed references that needed to run the project but every time i run the windows 10 universal project i get error **Unable to load DLL 'WinRT_CPPLayer.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**.

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: All of the runtime files you need to execute your program must be contained the appx package.  If one is missing then you'll get this error.  Why VS cannot write a valid manifest for the package, so it can get built properly with all required dependencies, is completely unclear from your question.  In chats about it in the Output window when you build the program that would be a start for documenting your question properly.  And read up on how you edit the manifest yourself.

Comment: Hi, I have added dll in the project and have set the property of DLL to 'Content' in build action and also 'Copy to output directory' to '' 'Copy Allways' but even then i get this error . I have also inspected the  "bin\x86\Debug" and  "bin\x86\Debug\AppX" both places i find the dll  but not working for me. Please help me. @Hans Passant

Comment: Is this a c++ project? If not you may need to add -cclib -lstdc++ linker flags in the project settings (Other Linker Flags files)

Comment: No its a Windows 10 Universal App Project created using C# and and in this i am trying to use a dll. @MalcolmMcCaffery